# Multilevel expandable Master-Details Datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, datatables

I am creating a multilevel expandable DataTable that can go upto n number of levels. For this, I have created a Partial View that is called from the Main View on click of 'Account' column in the table. Similarly, in the Partial View, I load the same Partial View again with different values of 'AccountID'. I have succeeded in expanding the DataTable upto 2 levels. 
My Controller Action is

```
public ActionResult GetChildTrialBalance(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate, int? pageNo, int? pageSize, int? AccountId)
        {
            fromDate = fromDate ?? DateTime.Today;// : fromDate;
            toDate = toDate ?? DateTime.Today;
            pageNo = pageNo ?? 1;
            pageSize = pageSize ?? 10;
            ViewBag.FromDate = fromDate;
            ViewBag.ToDate = toDate;
            IList<Ledger_DTO> listTrailBalance = null; 
            listTrailBalance = Ledgers.GetTrailBalance(BusinessId, UserId, fromDate, toDate, pageNo, pageSize, sortColumns, sortDirection);
            var selected = listTrailBalance.Where(x => x.ParentAccountId == AccountId).ToList();
            listTrailBalance = selected;
            return View(listTrailBalance);
        }
```

The Main View is

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var oTable;
            $('#TbTrialBalance tbody td span').click(function () {
                debugger;
                var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                if ($(this).data("status")=="open") {
                    $(this).data('status', 'closed');
                    oTable.fnClose(nTr);
                }
                else {
                    $(this).data('status','open');
                    var accountid = $(this).attr("rel");
                    $.get("GetChildTrialBalance?AccountId=" + accountid, function (trbals) {
                        oTable.fnOpen(nTr, trbals, 'details');
                    });
                }
            });

            /* Initialize table and make first column non-sortable*/
            oTable = $('#TbTrialBalance').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "aoColumns": [
                                    { "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false },
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
    .
    <!--removed for brevity-->
    .
<table id="TbTrialBalance">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>S.No</th>
<th>Account</th>
<th>Debit $</th>
<th>Credit</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 @foreach (StratusAccounting.Models.Ledger_DTO item in Model)
 {
 <tr>
  <td>@item.Sno</td>
 <td><span rel="@item.AccountId" style="cursor:pointer" data-status="closed">@item.Description</span></td>
 <td>@item.Debit</td>
 <td>@item.Credit</td>
 </tr>
 }
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Here is the Partial View

```
<script>

    $(function() {

        var oTable;
        $('#TbChildTrialBalance tbody td span').unbind('click').click(function () {
            debugger;
            var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            if ($(this).data("status") == "open") {
                $(this).data('status', 'closed');
                oTable.fnClose(nTr);
            }
            else {
                $(this).data('status', 'open');
                var accountid = $(this).attr("rel");
                $.get("GetChildTrialBalance?AccountId=" + accountid, function (trbals) {
                    oTable.fnOpen(nTr, trbals, 'details');
                });
            }
        });

        /* Initialize table and make first column non-sortable*/
        oTable = $('#TbChildTrialBalance').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                                { "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false },
                                null,
                                null,
                                null
            ]
        });
        });


</script>

<table id="TbChildTrialBalance">
 <thead>
<tr>
<th>S.No</th>
<th>Account</th>
<th>Debit $</th>
<th>Credit</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 @foreach (StratusAccounting.Models.Ledger_DTO item in Model)
 {
  <tr class="odd">
  <td class="hidden-480 ">@item.Sno</td>
  <td class="  sorting_1"><span rel="@item.AccountId" style="cursor:pointer" data-status="closed">@item.Description</span></td>
  <td class=" ">@item.Debit</td>
  <td class=" ">@item.Credit</td>
  </tr>
  }
 </tbody>
</table>
```

When I try to expand the 2nd level, the request goes to the Controller and I can see the data being returned fine. But I get the error like [image]

As the above image is a bit jumbled up, let me explain it to you.
SNo 1,2,3 are the Datatable rows from the View, Then SNo 5,6,8 are the Children of 3, When I expand the row with SNo 6, I get the error and it also shows SNo 9 which is the child of 6. Now if I click on SNo 9 which is having its children as well, the action is called and proper data is returned to the view, but no change happens in the View and there is no Javascript error raised in Console.
Now I am having the following questions:

1. Is my approach right? How would you solve such a problem?
2. How would you generate different IDs for tables in repetitive calls to
   the same Partial View?

Please bear with the lengthy question. I could not trim it further.
Kindly point me in the right direction.
******Update******
Got the answer to the 2nd problem by using `Class` as selector in the `Partial View`. Also got rid of the Error alert. Here is my updated Partial View. Please notice the changes.

```
<script>

    $(function() {

        var oTable;
        $('.clsChildTBal tbody td span').unbind('click').click(function () {
            debugger;
            var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            if ($(this).data("status") == "open") {
                $(this).data('status', 'closed');
                oTable.fnClose(nTr);
            }
            else {
                $(this).data('status', 'open');
                var accountid = $(this).attr("rel");
                $.get("GetChildTrialBalance?AccountId=" + accountid + "&fromDate=" + $("#fromDate").val() + "&toDate=" + $("#toDate").val(), function (trbals) {
                    oTable.fnOpen(nTr, trbals, 'details');
                });
            }
        });

        /* Initialize table and make first column non-sortable*/
        if (oTable != null)
            oTable.fnDestroy();
        oTable = $('.clsChildTBal').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                                { "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false },
                                null,
                                null,
                                null
            ],
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                $(oSettings.nTHead).hide();
            }
        });
        });


</script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width dataTable clsChildTBal" aria-describedby="sample_2_info">



                                    <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">

                                        @for(int i=0; i<Model.Count;i++)
                                        {
                                            int a = i + 1;
                                           <tr class="odd">
                                                <td class="serial-col">@a</td>
                                                 <td class="desc-col">@if(Model[i].IsParent==1){<span rel="@Model[i].AccountId" style="cursor:pointer" data-status="closed">@Model[i].Description</span>}
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                             @Model[i].Description;           }
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="debit-col">@Model[i].Debit</td>
                                                <td class="credit-col">@Model[i].Credit</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

But still I can't make it show data after 2 levels. Does go to the Action and fetch data but does not show data and No `Console` error as well.

Comment: Did u achieve it? I am currently exploring the options for multi Level grouping for a huge set of data (in  millions) which can be showed in groups and supports dragging of columns to show the column. `ngGrid` of AngularJS, `SlickGrid`, `IgniteUI PivotGrid`.

Comment: No @VivekVardhan, actually I changed my strategy to generating it through jQuery and havent seen that in for some time now. Anyways, thanks for the other possible options.

Comment: Actually, i was asking, if you would have completed, you might be able to help, because i am  in need. :)

Comment: @VivekVardhan, I have done it upto 2 levels as you can see, I suppose for your data, you can check if this code works.